# What sense does it make to declare a function more than one time in C?

Tags: c, function, prototype, declaration

I've seen a couple of times that the prototype declaration of a function in the header was literally repeated in the c-file.

It is possible to declare a function more than one time in C - but what sense does it make? Is it just for better readability or is there some deeper insight which I am missing?

Comment: It depends, can you show the specific situation you are talking about?

Comment: IMHO it's useless, but it doesn't harm either. But if the second declaration is different from the first one (in terms of number and types of parameters), then you'll get a compilation error.

Comment: Prolly an editing/copypasta error by author.

Comment: @iharob - actually I cannot give an example as i cannot see any pattern. I'm working on a new project and all function declarations of the header files are repeated in the c-files. For every module the same. All headers of the modules are summarized in one header file which is included in every module. So I would like to strictly move all global function declarations to the headers and have the module function declarations in the c-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible. It doesn't make any sense.

But it does not cause any harm either. You can declare a function as many times as you like, but each such declaration must be identical to the others. So it is pointless to do so. As someone suggested, maybe it is a copy/paste error.

You can only have one function *definition* though, which should always be in the c file.

---

This is how you *should* do it:

- Function declarations which is part of the caller's interface should be in the h file, and there only.
- Function declarations of local (private) functions that are only available from inside the c file itself, should be in the c file, and there only. Such functions should be declared and defined as `static`.

Answer (score 2):

Duplicate function declarations serve no useful *semantic* purpose, but they may arise for historical reasons, because of local coding conventions, or for some other reason.

For example, it may be a local coding convention that every function in each source file is prototyped at the beginning of that file.  That has some minor practical utility, such as serving as a manifest of the functions defined in each file, and making the functions inside each file able to ignore any concern about whether other functions in the same file are declared in a header.

Additionally, multiple declarations of the same function or object don't necessarily have to be *identical*, they only need to be *compatible*.  Under some circumstances it may makes sense to provide a less specific prototype in a header and a more specific one in the source file containing the function definition (which itself serves as yet another declaration).